# OData with Mongo: System.ArgumentException: 'The property 'Id' on type 'Item' must be a Complex property. (Parameter 'propertyInfo')'

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, odata

I'm trying to configure `.net core` with `OData` and `Mongo`.

I'm getting this error: `System.ArgumentException: 'The property 'Id' on type 'Item' must be a Complex property. (Parameter 'propertyInfo')'`

This is my configuration:

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
            {
               // something here
            })
            .AddOData(opt =>
            {
                opt.Count()
                    .Filter()
                    .Expand()
                    .Select()
                    .OrderBy()
                    .SetMaxTop(5000)
                    .AddRouteComponents("odata", GetEdmModel());

                opt.TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Utc;
            });

public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        var entitySetConfiguration = builder.EntitySet<Item>("Item");
        entitySetConfiguration.EntityType.HasKey(entity => entity.Id);

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

And my entity:

```
public class Item : Document
{
    public string SubCategory { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Document : IDocument
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt => Id.CreationTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public abstract class Document : IDocument
{
    //...
    public string IdStr => Id.ToString();
}
```